# How to create a Constructor so that i can pass the value

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

How to pass the float value from Main Activity to other or how to create a constructor for canvas draw on bitmap constructor for the given java class . I want to pass or Set this value to for ex: X=40, Y=30 and assign it in the  override method of DrawOnCanvas 
 canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, X, Y, null);
I have a implementation from github need to implement these values in this class:

```
public class WatermarkFilter extends GlOverlayFilter {

private Bitmap bitmap;
private Position position = Position.LEFT_TOP;
private Canvas canvas;


public WatermarkFilter(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}


public WatermarkFilter(Bitmap bitmap, Position position) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
    this.position = position;
}


@Override
protected void drawCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
    if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
        switch (position) {
            case LEFT_TOP:
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, "X", "Y", null);
                break;     
            case RIGHT_BOTTOM:
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, canvas.getWidth() - bitmap.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight() - bitmap.getHeight(), null);
                break;
        }
    }
}

public enum Position {
    LEFT_TOP,
    LEFT_BOTTOM,
    RIGHT_TOP,
    RIGHT_BOTTOM
}
```

}

From My MainClass method where i am using this method:

```
 float X = sticker.getMappedBoundPoints()[0];
   float Y = sticker.getMappedBoundPoints()[1];
    Log.d(TAG, "SavedVideo: " + "X" + X + "?/" + "Y" + Y);
 mp4Composer = new Mp4Composer(inputVideoPath, videoPath)
            .rotation(Rotation.ROTATION_270)
            .size(720, 720)
            .filter(new WatermarkFilter(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher_sample),WatermarkFilter.Position.LEFT_TOP))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Question i assume that you want to set X and Y float values in on Canvas method 
so simple create a constructor like

```
public WatermarkFilter(Bitmap bitmap, Float x, Float y) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
    X = x;
    Y = y;
 }
```

And set in the Override method:

```
@Override
protected void drawCanvas(Canvas canvas) {

    if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {

       canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,X,Y,null);
```

In Your MainActivity:

```
filter(new WatermarkFilter(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher_sample),X,Y))
```